# MySQL get value using data from three tables

Tags: mysql

I need to get one value from one table using information from other two.
Here is the structure:

### USERS TABLE

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
| ID        | NAME    | ZIP        |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| 1         | John    | 1111-222   |
| 2         | Maria   | 2222-555   |
| 3         | José    | 3333-505   |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

### ZIP-MATCH TABLE

```
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+
| DD        | CC      | PART1      | PART2      |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+
| 1         | 1       | 1111       | 101        |
| 1         | 1       | 1111       | 111        |
| 1         | 2       | 1111       | 222        |
| 1         | 3       | 2222       | 333        |
| 2         | 1       | 2222       | 100        |
| 2         | 1       | 2222       | 555        |
| 2         | 2       | 2244       | 222        |
| 2         | 2       | 2244       | 333        |
| 2         | 3       | 2245       | 311        |
| 3         | 1       | 3333       | 111        |
| 3         | 2       | 3333       | 222        |
| 3         | 3       | 3333       | 505        |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

### AREAS NAME TABLE

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
| DD        | CC      | AREA       |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| 1         | 1       | Lisboa     |
| 1         | 2       | Porto      |
| 1         | 3       | Aveiro     |
| 2         | 1       | Braga      |
| 2         | 2       | Fundão     |
| 2         | 3       | Bogas      |
| 3         | 1       | Faro       |
| 3         | 2       | Leiria     |
| 3         | 3       | Covilhã    |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

What I need to do is a query to get all users from the first table, with all the users data (ID, NAME, ZIP) plus the AREA name.
For this example it would be:

```
1, John, 1111-222, Porto
2, Maria, 2222-555, Braga
3, José, 3333-505, Covilhã
```

Thanks in advance,
Miguel.

Comment: join on all 3 tables and then select only the columns you are interested in?

Comment: @Diego This was one part from a bigger query, was stuck on this part, regarding this, I had nothing. But thanks for your time!

Comment: @Tom Ron Yes, i followed and answer bellow, and yes that's the way I did it. And thanks for your time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
SELECT 
a.id, 
a.name, 
a.zip, 
c.area

FROM

users a
LEFT JOIN
zip_match b

ON a.zip = concat(b.part1,'-',b.part2)

LEFT JOIN

areas_name c

ON b.dd = c.dd
and b.cc = c.cc;
```

Assuming your tables were called `users`, `zip_match` and `areas_name` respectively. Not sure of the data types of `part1` and `part2`, they might need to be converted into strings to work in the `concat` function.

Comment: Thanks this helped. I just changed one part, here, since the b.part1 and b.part2 are indexed, this way it's much faster

LEFT JOIN
zip_match b
ON CONVERT(SUBSTRING(a.zip, 1, LOCATE('-',a.zip) - 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) = b.part1
AND CONVERT(SUBSTRING(a.zip, LOCATE('-',a.zip)+1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) = b.part2

Answer (score 0):

```
select users.id, users.name, users.zip, areas.area from users u, zipmatch z, areas a
where u.zip = z.part1 + '-' + z.part2 
and a.dd = z.dd and a.cc = z.cc
```

perhaps?

Comment: I followed @mjsqu answer and it worked, adapted to my query. But thank you too for your time! Best regards.